# Unable to mount a 64Gb SD card on Qualcomm's SnapDragon 810 MDP smartphone

Tags: mount, sd-card

I tried to google but didn't see the problem reported anywhere yet.

I was playing around with a [Qualcomm's Snapdragon 810 MDP smartphone](http://www.androidauthority.com/snapdragon-810-mdp-smartphone-569294/), while developing an app which makes heavy usage of data stored in the SD card.

I have a San Disk Ultra 64GB, formatted exFat. It works without problems in a Note 4 (where, in fact, I also re-formatted it), but, although detected, I cannot get it mounted in the Snapdragon device. So far I could only mount an 8 Gb and a 16 Gb SanDisk card there.

Applying the Upgrade Package 2.2 available [here](http://support.intrinsyc.com/projects/mdp810s) (after registration) did not improve things.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in contact with Intrinsyc Support, apparently "only FAT32 is supported for that size".

Now the problem was to format with FAT32, as Windows (arbitrarily) doesn’t support formatting FAT32 above 32Gb.
I tried this tool but it didn’t work: 
http://tokiwa.qee.jp/EN/Fat32Formatter/

What worked was:

- Mount SD card on the phone
- Settings -> Storage -> SD card -> Erase USB Storage

Apparently this doesn't just "erase", but also format the drive FAT32 (as I could verify afterward mounting it on Windows). The SD card is now mounted and running!